# Underlining text using transition on page load with a delay

Tags: html, css

I've been at this for a while now, and so far I haven't gotten very far. I have this code (CSS) and I want to underline specific text (from middle to out) after about 8 seconds after the page load, I can only figure out the :hover part (I want the underline to appear 8s after the page has loaded in, without having to hover over the element):

```css
#sec {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
#sec:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
#sec:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

and the HTML:

```html
<div id="sec">our clone site is <a href="#" onclick="sitedownER()">currently down</a>. click <a href="update.html">here</a> for updates on the status of each site</div>
```

I am trying to get the `<div id="sec">` to underline 8s[econds] after the page has loaded.

Comment: you need a Jquery for this because it use a `.Ready()` function which detect when the page loaded and do your code

Comment: So you're saying add the Jquery at the end of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using animation (keyframes), check snippet

**PS:** Run snippet and wait for 8 seconds.

```css
#sec {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes border {
     from {width: 0px;}
     to {width:100%}
}

#sec:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: blue;  
  -webkit-animation-name: border; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: border;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="sec">our clone site is <a href="#" onclick="sitedownER()">currently down</a>. click <a href="update.html">here</a> for updates on the status of each site</div>
```

Comment: This has helped a lot, but I need the underline to stay visible after it being displayed, is there a way for that?

Comment: Is there a way to change the thickness of the line?

Comment: change the `height`